# IIS7.5 website (mostly) inaccessible from the outside world

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, iis-7.5

On the network firewall, I opened up port 80 and forwarded it to the Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5. Port 80 is open in the Windows firewall.

On the LAN, the website is accessible without any trouble. When accessed from the outside, I can access it only 3 times every few hours before access to it cuts out from the outside and the browser displays the error message "cannot display webpage".

There aren't any access limits in IIS or the network's firewall as far as I can tell.

IIS is running PHP 5.3. The default website has been deleted. The bindings for the website's domain are set for `mydomain.com *:80` and `mydomain.com 192.168.0.3:80`

[edit]: Just to check if there was some problem with the firewall or ISP in using port 80, I set up the firewall with port forwarding for 8081 externally to 80 for the LAN. The domain/website/page was still inaccessible by a browser outside of the network.

[Edit2]: The DNS entry for the domain resolves to the correct external IP. If I attempt to access the website via the external IP, it loads three times, then ceases to be accessible with the browser message "cannot display the webpage".

Comment: Can you define "access to it cuts out from the outside"? I assume "Page Does Not Exist" errors...

Comment: What do you see in the app log, system log and W3SVC logs in the relevant time frame?

Comment: If it works fine on the local LAN you most likely have some router/gateway NAT issues or ISP issues.  You will most likely need to post some additional information regarding that side of your network to get some help.

Comment: @Somantra: I get a "cannot display the webpage" browser error.

Comment: The firewall is the only gateway device. Other ports that I have opened to the server are functioning properly. The domain is resolving to the WAN IP address.

Comment: The app and system logs show no errors/warnings. The W3SVC logs show the GET requests from the LAN visits and from my outside IP. There are no errors displayed.

Comment: @ForceFlow, do you get the same results browsing the public IP externally?

Comment: Yes, but I deleted the default website so there isn't anything that is supposed to respond anyway

Comment: I am not sure what the default website has to do with it, but it appears to be a DNS problem if you are reliably able to access the website using the public IP address.

Comment: ok, I added a bind in IIS with blank domain for *:80. Upon visiting the external IP address, the webpage appeared in the browser.

Comment: Good, so that would seem to indicate a DNS problem. If all your external testing hit the same Name Server(s) then you might try different Name server(s). In other words you might want to test in other external environments to rule out an overwhelmed Name server.

Comment: ok, I take that back. After refreshing the page in the browser a few times while visiting it via the external IP, it stopped being accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address was already in use by another device (which was undocumented). The device was also secured against ping requests and port scans, so it appeared as though there was nothing there. I only found out about it when I called the ISP and they looked at the ARP table in the modem and saw a MAC address (which was unknown to me) assigned to the IP address.